# Hide Shared With in a Modal Pop up Dialog

Tags: 2013, css, ribbon, modal-dialog, popup

I need to *hide or disable* the **Shared With** button in the top ribbon bar of a *Modal Pop Up dialog*.
I tried this CSS but no luck:

```
#Ribbon\.ListForm\.Display\.Manage\.ManagePermissions-Medium
{
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked in my environment:

```
#Ribbon\.ListForm\.Display\.Manage-LargeMedium-1-1{
    display:none;
}
```

Use your browser's dev tools to find the exact 'id' in your instance. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Finding Ribbon Button ID]

Comment: I used developer tool to check the id, but seems that the css are not included